# How do I export the debugging configuration property of a VS 2019 property page?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I am using visual studio 2019, and I have a project that has an environment variable set for the debugging property of my project that I cannot figure out how to export/import.

In order to get the project to build, I need to specify the debugging environment path, and I need a solution that allows me to set this environment path by importing a property sheet, or a universal solution that does not require manually setting the environment path.

When I follow the steps found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=msvc-170), I cannot find a property that allows me to automate setting the debugging environment setting. [This is what I see with the property sheet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNtTX.png)

What I need to be able to do is delete the environment setting of my debugging configuration property, and import something that restores that setting, so that the solution can be applied to other machines.
[This is what I am referring to when I describe the setting I need to automate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHrXx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio IDE and follow step:

- *Tools > Import and Export Settings > Export selected environment settings*

Select the features you want to export from the window that opens (*Options > Debugging*) and click the *Next* button to select the directory where the file with the `.vssettings` extension will be saved.

[image]

The XML section in the `*.vssettings` file that starts with the statement shown below contains the shared Visual Studio IDE debug settings:

```xml
<Category name="Debugger" ...
```

###### References

- [How to: Reset Your Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms247075(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: When I test this by exporting my settings when the debugging environment path is set correctly, deleting the environment path, importing the recently exported settings with the same wizard, the setting does not restore. Does this mean I am experiencing a bug, or is this not the intended use?

Comment: I tested it now; When I restore the data in my local, there is no problem. If you've tampered with sensitive files that you shouldn't have tampered with to achieve this task, this may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: To reset VS settings, you can try reading this article: [Environment settings for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2022) - _Reset Settings_

Comment: I tried this with a fresh install of vs 2019 and a new project, and it did not work. To be clear, this process of using the import/export settings wizard should repopulate empty debugging environment settings in the project property pages if that same setting was not empty when the settings were originally exported?